# Group by records, generate new ObjectId, and change resulting set structure

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am working on a music database containing band and genre records, each band having multiple genres.
I imported my data from a CSV and obtained a collection that looks like this:

[image: Temporary Band - Genres relation collection]

What I now intend to do is to create a new collection of genres, which is the result of aggregating this collection by `genre_name`, allowing for the different kinds of genres to be placed separately.

For that, I managed to create the following aggregate operation:

```
db.tempBandGenres.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                name: "$genre_name"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $out: "genres"
    }
])
```

As intended, this outputs a collection of documents representing genres:

[image: Genres Collection Aggregate]

There are now two things I would like to do but can't figure out how: add a new `ObjectId` to each record in the genres collection and change the structure of each document so that the `name` attribute is not part of the `_id` element, being an attribute of the root instead.

So, a record example of the final collection would be:

[image: Desired Collection Record]

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to structure the result before `$out`,

- `$group` by `genre_name` and get first `_id`
- `$project` to show required fields

```
db.tempBandGenres.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$genre_name",
      id: { $first: "$_id" }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: "$id",
      name: "$_id"
    }
  },
  { $out: "genres" }
])
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This sugestion allowed me to solve the ID problem! But regarding the structure, I now have a name object containing a child name

Comment: Changing to name: "$_id.id" in the $project stage solved the second problem! Thanks

Comment: just see `$group` stage i have used `_id: "$genre_name"` it should work